# Mapping data with topojson and D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

so here is my first implementation using D3's library to create a map with U.S. counties.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>

<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>

<script>

  'use strict';

   let path = d3.geoPath();

   let svg = d3.select("svg");

    d3.queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
      .await(ready)


    function ready(error, us) {

      if (error) throw error;

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)

    }
```

simple and straight forward. it works. However when I change the src to a better json with the names in the props of each county object:

```
d3.queue()
 .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NealTaylor715/a08cc300e661aa45c464fa1e553b6f33/raw/eaa03db6827f2d6435b3898cae6fba03d6f55956/USCounties.json")
 .await(ready);
```

the map breaks. I get a blank SVG with this little gray blotch. the weird thing is that the data is appending to the path, just not the way I thought it should. Any pointers? Is my new JSON just not formatted correctly. The names on the objects' *properties* property are a necessity for the functionality I am shooting for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both data sources are formatted correctly, but they are different in one regard, one is projected while one is not.

The dataset in your first code block is already projected, that is to say it has already been transformed from points on a 3 dimensional ellipsoid to points on a Cartesian plane. We can tell they are not latitude longitude pairs as the coordinates, when converting to regular geojson, show points such as `...[649.7055250753067,200.18804561250514]...`

The dataset in your second code block is unprojected (or 'projected' with WGS84 or some other datum). It is made up of points that represent degrees north/south and degrees east/west. Converting this topojson to regular geojson we see coordinates like: `...[-167.36922883183183,53.30289293393393]...`

With already projected data, and no geoTransform ([API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoTransform), [example](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/496078bd5e37fd22a9b43fd6be84b36b)), you are simply taking the coordinates in the dataset and converting them to SVG coordinate space with no transform.

With unprojected data, you need to use a projection, such as d3.geoAlbers, to properly scale and transform your lat long pairs, points on an ellipsoid, to x,y points on a plane.